# Recycling paper at home

Tags: recycling, paper

What are, in your opinion or according to your direct experience, the easiest and most convenient way to recycle and re-use paper at home?

Comment: Turn it over and write on the other side ;-)

Comment: Well, is there a way to whiten it back at home?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ask my colleagues to keep the papers they print and do not use anymore, and I pile them up, cut them in half and make two holes at the top. I bind them together with a binder ring and I have a new notepad!

If the paper is soiled, I compost it (bakery paper bags, tissues). 
If it is office paper, after I wrote on both sides, I use it in my garden to layer the bottom of my pots and planters. I also use them at the bottom of the litter box for my cat, it makes cleaning up easier and I can compost everything at once. 
If the paper looks nice or if it has colorful pictures on it (old magazines, Christmas catalogues), I use it to wrap gifts, with a bit of burlap ribbon. 
Finally, I use it to wrap fragile items when I put away seasonal decorations: Christmas ornaments, holiday dishes etc.

You can also re-use it and make papier mâché sculptures if you have children, you just need water and flour and a bit of patience.

Comment: In case of office paper, is the printer ink safe for the garden environment ?

Answer (score 4):

Some people make briquettes from paper to burn them in their oven for heating, see for example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ki8OsYh0ksA

This is quite tediuos work. Also, the exhaust fumes and the remaining ashes are toxic, since paper consists up to 30% of filler, like calcium carbonate, cement and other. Therefore, in germany it is forbidden to burn paper briquettes in home fireplaces, since these don't have a special filtering of the exhaust fumes and a proper disposal of the ashes.